# How to unit test a NodeJs REST API server built using Express + Mongoose?

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, rest, mongoose, express

I have a REST API server that uses Express, Mongoose and [config](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config). I want to unit test my API. Basically, bring up a temporary web server on port x, an empty mongo-database on port y, do some API calls (both gets and puts) and validate what I get back and then shutdown temporary server and drop test database once my tests finish. What is the best way to do this? I have been looking at [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/)/[rewire](http://jhnns.github.com/rewire/) but not sure how to set up temporary server and db and not sure what the best practices are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found exactly what I was looking for: [testrest](https://github.com/DamonOehlman/testrest). I don't like its .txt file based syntax - I adapted to use a .json file instead for my specs.

Comment: looks interesting but the documentation seems non-existent... did you find any useful examples to get up and running?

Answer (score 6):

I use [Jenkins](http://www.jenkins-ci.org) (continuous integration server) and [Mocha](http://www.mochajs.org) to test my app, and I found myself having the same problem as you. I configured Jenkins so it would execute this shell command:

```
npm install
NODE_ENV=testing node app.js &
npm mocha
pkill node
```

This runs the server for executing the tests, and then kills it. This also sets the NODE_ENV environment variable so I can run the server on a different port when testing, since Jenkins already uses port 8080.

Here is the code:

app.js:

```
...
var port = 8080
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "testing")
    port = 3000;
...
```

test.js:

```
var request = require('request'),
    assert = require('assert');

    describe('Blabla', function() {
      describe('GET /', function() {
        it("should respond with status 200", function(done) {
          request('http://127.0.0.1:3000/', function(err,resp,body) {
            assert.equal(resp.statusCode, 200);
            done(); 
          }); 
        }); 
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend giving [Buster.JS](http://busterjs.org/) a try. You can do Asynchronous tests, mocks/stubs, and fire up a server.

Answer (score 0):

There its also [api-easy](https://github.com/flatiron/api-easy) build on top of [vows](https://github.com/cloudhead/vows), seems to be easy to use the first, but the second its much flexible and powerful

Comment: Not sure how you'd manage firing up the temporary node server using alternate configuration settings using api-easy and/or vows.

Comment: how did you try to configure your test?

Answer (score 0):

There is no *right* way, but I did create a seed application for my personal directory structure and includes the vows tests suggested by @norman784.

You can clone it: `git clone https://github.com/hboylan/express-mongoose-api-seed.git`

Or with npm: `npm install express-mongoose-api-seed`